# Saving data with saveAll() in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

This might not be the problem with saveAll, the situation is like this. I have table messages, and table sent_messages, which holds message id and user id. Models are created, where Messaage hasMany SentMessage, and SentMessage belongsTo Message. I need to save just one message in *messages* table, and save user ids and message id in *sent_messages* table. The problem starts when I try to save that in MessageController. Here is the code:

```
function custom() {
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->loadModel('User');
        $userIDs = $this->User->listActiveUsers();
        $this->data['Message']['message_type_id'] = 2;
        if ($this->Message->save($this->data)) {
            array_pop($this->data);
            foreach ($userIDs as $key => $value ) {
                $this->data['SentMessage'][$key]['user_id'] = $value;
                $this->data['SentMessage'][$key]['message_id'] = $this->Message->getLastInsertID();
            }
            //die($this->Message->SentMessage->saveAll($this->data));

            if ($this->Message->SentMessage->saveAll($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Data saved', 'success');   
            }
            else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Data not saved', 'error');
            }    
        }
    }  
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And what is the problem exactly?

Comment: The problem is it wont save data to sent_messages table. It saves data to message table but not in sent_messages. And any suggestions on using loadModel this way? Is it good practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your issue come from using "$key" as key for $userIDs array, saveAll take unindexed array for hasMany relations as parameters.

More-over, saveAll is perfect to save two related model in same time. Here something that should work :

```
function custom() {
  if (!empty($this->data)) {
    $this->loadModel('User');
    
    $this->data['Message']['message_type_id'] = 2;
    
    $userIDs = $this->User->listActiveUsers();
    foreach ($userIDs as $value ) {
        $this->data['SentMessage'][]['user_id'] = $value;
    }

    if ($this->Message->saveAll($this->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Data saved', 'success');   
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Data not saved', 'error');
    }    

  }  
}
```

Check the doc ! http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data

About using loadModel, I suppose that your SentMessage model is related to User, so you can use : $this->Message->SentMessage->User. But well no idea of which is the more efficient.

Comment: I am aware that saveAll does that, saves to related model at the same time... But I need to save data into sent_messages with id of recently saved message data. This listActiveUsers function returns nicely sorted list of user ids something like array( '0' => '45', ... ). I will try your solution and see if it works. Thanks anyway.

Comment: saveAll is supposed to automatically take care of adding ids for your related models. Avoiding you to do it manually.

Comment: I found the solution, as you said about automatically taking care of ids, I just added data to $this->data array and saved it like $this->Message->saveAll(). Problem was problably line where I manualy added messaged_id to the data array, and created condusion to Cake. Thanks olivier, you helped.

Answer (score 1):

**Easiest Way to save all data in cakephp**

```
$this->ModelName->saveAll($data_array);
```

**Note :** name of the fields in table and in array should be same.